# Column Split into columns and rows in R

Tags: r

My Data looks like

```
df <- data.frame(user_id=c('13','15'), 
                 answer_id = c('{"row[0][0]":"A","row[0][1]":"B","row[0][2]":"C","row[0][3]":"D","row[1][0]":"A1","row[1][1]":"B1","row[1][2]":"C1","row[1][3]":"D1"}', '{"row[0][0]":"W","row[0][1]":"X","row[0][2]":"Y","row[0][3]":"Z","row[1][0]":"W1","row[1][1]":"X1","row[1][2]":"Y1","row[1][3]":"Z1"}
'))
```

Desired data view

```
user_id       answer_id1      answer_id2    answer_id3     answer_id4
13                 A                B             C            D
13                 A1               B1            C1           D1
15                 W                X             Y            Z
15                 W1               X1            Y1           Z1
```

i'm new with R and hope to get solution soon as i do always

Comment: Whoever gave you this data is your enemy.  Never trust him.

Comment: Your data look to be JSON (I'm presuming this is just an example of how the real data look like). If so, have a look at the jsonlite package, you can turn this type of data into lists and then dataframes quite easily in R.

Comment: yap i have code for JSON, but  got some excel files and hectic job it was but thanks got the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may not be the *best* solution but this can get you from your sample input to your desired output using `stringr`, `purrr`, & `tidyr`.  See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DmGGDM/1) for an explanation of the regex used in the `stringr::str_match_all()` call.

```
df <- data.frame(user_id=c('13','15'), 
                 answer_id = c('{"row[0][0]":"A","row[0][1]":"B","row[0][2]":"C","row[0][3]":"D","row[1][0]":"A1","row[1][1]":"B1","row[1][2]":"C1","row[1][3]":"D1"}', '{"row[0][0]":"W","row[0][1]":"X","row[0][2]":"Y","row[0][3]":"Z","row[1][0]":"W1","row[1][1]":"X1","row[1][2]":"Y1","row[1][3]":"Z1"}'), 
                 stringsAsFactors=F)

#use regex to extract row ids and answers
regex_matches     <- stringr::str_match_all(df$answer_id, '\\"row\\[(\\d+)\\]\\[(\\d+)\\]\\":\\"([^\\"]*)\\"')
#add user id to each result
answers_by_user   <- purrr::map2(df$user_id, regex_matches, ~cbind(.x, .y[,-1]))
#combine list of matrices and convert to df
answers_df        <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, answers_by_user))
#add meaningful names
names(answers_df) <- c("user_id", "row_1", "row_2", "value")
#convert to wide
spread_row_1      <- tidyr::spread(answers_df, row_1, value)
final_df          <- tidyr::spread(answers_df, row_2, value)
#remove row column
final_df$row_1    <- NULL 
#clean up names
names(final_df)   <- c("user_id", "answer_id1", "answer_id2", "answer_id3", "answer_id4")
final_df

#output
  user_id answer_id1 answer_id2 answer_id3 answer_id4
1      13          A          B          C          D
2      13         A1         B1         C1         D1
3      15          W          X          Y          Z
4      15         W1         X1         Y1         Z1
```

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean.  it might be worth posting another question if you need to show desired output to fully describe what you want

Comment: df <- data.frame(user_id=c('13','15','13','19'), 
                 answer_id = c('{"row[0][0]":"A","row[0][1]":"B","row[0][2]":"C","row[0][3]":"D","row[1][0]":"A1","row[1][1]":"B1","row[1][2]":"C1","row[1][3]":"D1"}', '{"row[0][0]":"W","row[0][1]":"X","row[0][2]":"Y","row[0][3]":"Z","row[1][0]":"W1","row[1][1]":"X1","row[1][2]":"Y1","row[1][3]":"Z1"}
','{"row[0][0]":"A","row[0][1]":"B","row[0][2]":"C","row[1][0]":"A1","row[1][1]":"B1","row[1][2]":"C1"}','{"row[0][0]":"P","row[0][1]":"Q","row[0][2]":"R"}')) <want to separate/drop the duplicate record which is not completed n NA for Incomplete

Answer (score 1):

Column 2 looks like JSON, so you could do something like this to get it into a form that you can do something with...

```
library(rjson)
df2 <- lapply(1:nrow(df),function(i) 
            data.frame(user=df[i,1],
            answer=unlist(fromJSON(as.character(df[i,2]))),stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
df2 <- do.call(rbind,df2)
df2[,"r1"] <- gsub(".+\\[(\\d)]\\[(\\d)].*","\\1",rownames(df2)) 
df2[,"r2"] <- gsub(".+\\[(\\d)]\\[(\\d)].*","\\2",rownames(df2)) 

df2
           user answer r1 r2
row[0][0]    13      A  0  0
row[0][1]    13      B  0  1
row[0][2]    13      C  0  2
row[0][3]    13      D  0  3
row[1][0]    13     A1  1  0
row[1][1]    13     B1  1  1
row[1][2]    13     C1  1  2
row[1][3]    13     D1  1  3
row[0][0]1   15      W  0  0
row[0][1]1   15      X  0  1
row[0][2]1   15      Y  0  2
row[0][3]1   15      Z  0  3
row[1][0]1   15     W1  1  0
row[1][1]1   15     X1  1  1
row[1][2]1   15     Y1  1  2
row[1][3]1   15     Z1  1  3
```

Comment: yap it was exported from JSON i guess donno much about, works great thanks :D